# Perform Spatial Adjustment or Georefenced using two ArcMaps?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, georeferencing, spatial-adjustment

I have DWG files that need to be georeferenced to a known coordinate system because they were from AutoCAD that doesn't have projected coordinate system.

I have an JPEG file that I extracted from a basemap for the same peculiar area.

Has anyone ever tried using spatial adjustment and georeference with two open ArcMap ?

For Example, you have an unprojected layer on Arcmap 1 and you have known projected coordinate system imagery on another ArcMap 2.

I am wondering if those would work ? or Must I stick with just one ArcMap ?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot imagine why you would want to try using Spatial Adjustment and/or Georeferencing between two open sessions of ArcMap, and I think having two sessions of ArcMap open at the same time is generally unwise when editing due to the likelihood of schema locks.

As [@FelixIP commented](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/168883/perform-spatial-adjustment-or-georefenced-using-two-arcmaps#comment251716_168898):

> Moreover there is Viewer Window available and most convenient thing to
>   use for spatial adjustment.

I also find the Magnifier window invaluable when georeferencing.